# How to move slider on slide based not pixel Based in Gliderjs | Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am using Glider.js in my project. It is working perfectly as my requirement but, only when I drag/touch-swipe slide, it moves like scrolling.

I want, when I drag/touch-swipe, next/previous slide should appear not partial slide?
Please guide me on how can I achieve this.

here is the [demo link](https://nickpiscitelli.github.io/Glider.js/) of Glider.js

here is [Github file](https://github.com/NickPiscitelli/Glider.js)

here is working demo

```css
* {
            box-sizing: border-box
        }
        html, body {
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .glider{
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .glider-contain {
            width: 90%;
            max-width: 997px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .glider-slide {
            min-height: 150px;
        }
        .glider-slide img {
            width: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"> <style type="text/css">@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important;}</style>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/glider-js@1/glider.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/glider-js@1/glider.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener('load',function(){

        window._ = new Glider(document.querySelector('.glider'), {
            slidesToShow: 5, //'auto',
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            itemWidth: 150,
            draggable: true,
            scrollLock: false,
            rewind: false,
            arrows: {
                prev: '.glider-prev',
                next: '.glider-next'
            }
        });
          
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="glider-contain">
        <div class="glider">
            <div><img alt="Test" src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=1"></div>
            <div><img alt="Test" src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=2"></div>
            <div><img alt="Test" src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=3"></div>
            <div><img alt="Test" src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=4"></div>
            <div><img alt="Test" src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=5"></div>
            <div><img alt="Test" src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=6"></div>
            <div><img alt="Test" src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=7"></div>
            <div><img alt="Test" src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=8"></div>
            <div><img alt="Test" src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=9"></div>
            <div><img alt="Test" src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=10"></div>
            <div><img alt="Test" src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=11"></div>
            <div><img alt="Test" src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=12"></div>
            <div><img alt="Test" src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=13"></div>
            <div><img alt="Test" src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=14"></div>
            <div><img alt="Test" src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=15"></div>
            <div><img alt="Test" src="http://placehold.it/300x300?text=16"></div>
        </div>
        <button class="glider-prev">&laquo;</button>
        <button class="glider-next">&raquo;</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't decipher what you're trying to say

Comment: @Phaelaxz sorry for my bad English, when I scroll slider it moves pixel-wise I want it to move slider wise when I drag left it shoudl display next/previous slide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the documentation of Glider, I got few options which can make it work as a requirement. Posting answer as it can be helpful for somone else.

this can make a trick

```
scrollLock : true
```

**If the value is true, Glider.js will scroll to the nearest slide after any scroll interactions**

```
glider.scrollTo(pixelOffset);
```

**it will Scroll directly to supplied scroll position in pixels**

Hope it might helpful for somone else.